# 50 and 60 Hertz, what is the visible effect?

Tags: voltage

I hope this isn't too noob of a question for this community and that the title is worded correctly...

I've got a few devices from Europe I'm using in Canada that are naturally 50Hz. I have to pro level transformers (not Samsonite ones from an airport, LOL) that are doing the job for these devices perfectly and with no real visible or audible difference. So, I'm wondering for example with my hand blender and food processor... the basic science answer is that the motors are going to spin faster. But is there a way to get a quantitative sense of what the extra cycles are doing to the appliances I use the transformer with other than, the manufacturer built it to work for 50 and you're making it spin faster? Should I use them at lower speeds, in shorter bursts?
Apologies if my terminology and descriptions are completely amateur.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Some type of motors (synchronous, shaded pole, split-phase etc.) will operate 20% faster on 60Hz as compared to 50Hz, with somewhat less torque.

Others, such as the universal motors used in small appliances don't really care so long as the voltage is okay. The higher frequency is unlikely to cause such appliances to significantly misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

In many home appliances you will find so called serial motors. These motors are designed for universal use. In other words it does not matter if they are used with 50HZ or 60Hz. The only thing to keep in mind is the applied voltage.

appliances that have no motor (power supplies) only have a transformer or a socalled inverter. Both these systems are also insensitive to the difference in frequency.

Larger motors such as can be found in refrigerators, freezers, etc run some 20 % faster on 60 Hz then on 50 Hz but there is also no problem. The appliances are mostly designed in such a way that both frequencies can be handled properly.

Comment: Commutation motors work better at lower frequencies, less circumference fire. But 50Hz is already bad for these motors, 60Hz is only a bit more worse. That's why the catenary frequency of electric trains is 25Hz in the US and Canada and even lower, 16.7Hz, in Germany, Austria, Switzerland, Sweden, Norway.

Answer (score 0):

Speed will increase with no load, but vary more with load and 20% more temperature rise at max torque load, but unlikely be a risk.

The load speed regulation error is contributed by local step up transformer higher impedance and 20% more back EMF from higher synchronous AC is not a problem unless you stall the motor.

No worries.

Answer (score 0):

Your hand blender and food processor are very likely to have "universal" motors in them (as most kitchen appliances do).  Universal motors will operate at essentially the SAME speed whether you are powering them from 50Hz or 60Hz (or even DC). That is why the are called "universal".

Few, if any, modern appliances or electronic gear is dependent on mains frequency.  Back in the bad old days things like vintage LP turntables and tape recorders (and old clocks) used the mains frequency for speed control. But here in the 21st century virtually all mains-frequency dependent gadgets are relegated to the museum.